# Typecasting a json tuple into a string Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, websocket, casting

How would I be able to turn a JSON of class type `tuple` into a `string` without turning the numbers into strings as well. I am getting a json object in the form of a tuple from a websocket and I am trying to convert it into a string form like `data`.

```
data= '''
({
    'ext_code': '',
    'ext_info': '',
    'rate_limit': 120,
    'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1620081183677,
    'rate_limit_status': 117,
    'result': {
        'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00087168, 'cum_realised_pnl': 7.288e-05, 'equity': 0.00087168, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.00087168},
        'EOS': {'available_balance': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 0, 'equity': 0, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0},
        'ETH': {'available_balance': 0.03362706, 'cum_realised_pnl': -7.41e-06, 'equity': 0.03362706, 'given_cash': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'service_cash': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'used_margin': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.03362706}
    },
    'ret_code': 0,
    'ret_msg': 'OK',
    'time_now': '1620081183.700541'},
    <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x0000016DC011F888>)
 '''
```

Comment: What you have above is not valid JSON, there is no "JSON tuple". Also, `<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x0000016DC011F888>` is not valid JSON... this looks like you did `str(some_python_tuple)`

Comment: I got it from a websocket connection

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. That isn't JSON, which should be obvious, it isn't even using double-quotes. Whatever is providing that string is simply doing something like `str(my_python_object)` and pretending that is serialization. It isn't.